# Custom CSS dropdown to focus on dropdown elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility

I am trying to get the dropdown elements to focus while the list is in open state using CSS. Right now, the autofocus only selects the All, then closes the list dropdown.  I want it to focus on cheese in an open state and focus tab through Toast and any components that could be after. I have tried placing tabIndex on each element, but the list dropdown closes so I don't see the focus.

Please, see [CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-thunder-0xii6?file=/src/App.js).

```css
.select-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.select-box-current:hover {
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}

.select-box-current:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #8CB6FD, 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.1), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.2);
}

.select-box-current {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.select-box-current:focus+.select-box-list {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: none;
}

.select-box-current:focus+.select-box-list .select-box-option {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select-box-value {
  display: flex;
}

.select-box-input {
  display: none;
}

.select-box-input:checked+.select-box-input-text {
  display: block;
}

.select-box-input-text {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.select-box-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: HideList;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: step-start;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.select-box-option {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.select-box-option:hover {
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.05);
}

.select-box-option:focus {
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #8CB6FD;
}

@keyframes HideList {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div className="select-box">
  <div className="select-box-current" tabIndex="0" autoFocus={true}>
    <div className="select-box-value">
      <input className="select-box-input" type="radio" id={0} value="all" name="Ben" defaultChecked />
      <p className="select-box-input-text">
        All
      </p>
    </div>

    <div key={idx} className="select-box-value">
      <input className="select-box-input" type="radio" id={1} value="Cheese" name="Ben" />
      <p className="select-box-input-text">
        Cheese
      </p>
    </div>

    <div className="select-box-value">
      <input className="select-box-input" type="radio" id={2} value="Toast" name="Ben" />
      <p className="select-box-input-text">
        Toast
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <ul className="select-box-list">
    <li>
      <label className="select-box-option" htmlFor={0} aria-hidden={false}>
                            All
                        </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label className="select-box-option" htmlFor={1} aria-hidden={false}>
                                Cheese
                            </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label className="select-box-option" htmlFor={2} aria-hidden={false}>
                                Toast
                            </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what dropdown elements you're referring to. All I see in your example is some radio inputs and then an unordered list right after. Please provide additional context.

Comment: I use divs to imitate a behaviour of a dropdown

Comment: The example you give doesn't make it very clear I am afraid. Are you trying to make a custom select component (and struggling with maintaining focus within the drop-down). Also you marked this as accessibility but said you want to allow users to tab through options, this is not how a `<select>` (which is what I presume you are trying to create) works, instead it is open with enter and use arrow keys to navigate to items, enter to close (or just navigate with arrow keys without opening). Does https://codepen.io/asna_farid/pen/fKChk have the *functionality* you are after?

Comment: use tabindex it will help to navigate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a little you can easily do this by just switch its class back and forth.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("something").classList.toggle(".open")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should force this pure CSS `focus` implementation. The reason is: you can only have 1 element focused. That is why the dropdown closes when 1 of the dropdown items is focused on.

I recommend to solve this by switching from psuedo class `:focus` to class `active` for the dropdown items

```
.select-box-option.active {
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #8cb6fd;
}
```

Track the active item via state that updates when a different input is selected

```
const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = React.useState("cheese");

<input
  className="select-box-input"
  type="radio"
  id={1}
  value="toast"
  name="Ben"
  onChange={() => setActiveItem("toast")}
/>
```

And as mentioned by the others, you can use arrow navigation for the User Experience, because again, using tab will cause issues because it will change `focus` and close your dropdown.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    // down arrow key
  } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    // up arrow key
  }
}
```

[image: Edit htmlFor]